# Replace settings in dotnetcore app using VSTS Test task

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines-build-task

How would I go about changing settings like connectionstrings and what not in a dotnet core application for a unit test project to run it in VSTS build. There is mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) on aspnetcore applications but I'm testing a class library. Using runsettings might help but the override parameters option is not present like in the old run tests task.

Comment: Where do you store connectionstrings?

Comment: Appsettings.json, but I don't want passwords etc in source control

Comment: You can use Secret Variables https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables

Comment: Yes but the focus of the article is to define the variables. I still needed a way to get them picked up by the unit test. The dotnet test command has no options to do so. I could use the runsettings file but then I need to write a powershell command to edit the file etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) step/task to replace the value.

Comment: That's indeed what I did but thought there was a built in solution.